# nginx responds to HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: docker, nginx, http-status-code-503, nextcloud

I am using the dockerized Nextcloud as shown here: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy-self-signed-ssl/mariadb/fpm

I set this up with port 80 mapped to 12345 and port 443 mapped to 12346. When I go to `https://mycloud.example.com:12346`, I get the self-signed certificate prompt, but otherwise everything is fine and I see the NextCloud web UI. But when I go to `http://mycloud.example.com:12345` nginx (the `proxy` container) gives error "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable". The error also shows up in `proxy`'s logs.

How can I diagnose the issue? Why is HTTPS working but not HTTP?

Comment: My guess is it’s specifically configured not to be available over non-secure http. You’ll have to dig around in the documentation for a way to configure it or just crack open the source in your IDE and debug the request line by line...

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide your docker command starting nextcloud, or docker-compose file ?

Diagnosis is as usual with docker stuff : get the id for the currently running container

`docker ps`

Then check the logs

`docker logs [id or name of your container]
docker-compose logs [name of your service]`

Connect in the container

`docker exec -ti [id or name of your container] [bash or ash if alpine based container]`

There read the nginx conf files involved. In your case I'ld check the redirection being made from http to https, most likely it's something like below with no specific port specified for https, hence port 443, hence not working

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;    <======== no port = 443
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; 

       [....]
}
```

Comment: Well, I've already linked to a docker-compose file, so the command is of course `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @Wassinger my bad for the linked file. 

Regarding debugging, as I said if you use unconventional ports (12345 and 12346), the issue is most likely HTTP behing redirected by default to 443 and not 12346.

Something like `docker-compose exec proxy "cat /etc/nginx/vhost.d/*"` should dump the nginx vhost config to check that.

And here are example of jwilder fiddling with ports if you really want to https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/search?q=WEB_PORTS

Comment: Seems like `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/` is empty for proxy

Comment: Also I did find that in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf/` there is a block for port 80 with no 443 like you mention at the end of your answer. The other block with 443 contains a `location / {proxy_pass https://mycloud.example.com;}` as well, I wonder if this is related?

Comment: The empty block is if I recall correctly jwilder's dockergen script failing to properly generate the conf. There should be a file named [your_VIRTUAL_HOST].conf.

The reason for that might lie in the proxy logs, check `docker-compose logs proxy`